# sculpting - no clean edges

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, vertices, sculpting

I am sculpting a column and noticed, that my edges vertically are very smooth, but when I do them horizontally they are rough. I want them smooth and clean, but I don't want to use the smoothing-brush. It just should work look the horizontal line. Why do they look different and how can I achieve the clean edges? Thank you for helping!

[image]

Comment: Is scale applied for the object? (Object mode > Ctrl+A) How does topology of the mesh look like?

Comment: Ctrl+A worked. Thank you !!
!!